# Conditional Maven mirror in settings.xml?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In my settings.xml I have a mirror entry like this:

```xml
<mirror>
    <id>corporate-vpn</id>
    <name>Approved Corporate Java</name>
    <url>https://some-url-available-in-vpn-only/repository/maven-public</url>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

This works like a charm as long as I'm connected to the VPN. Occasionally it isn't available, so I would need to connect directly to Maven Central (and others). Currently I do that by commenting out the mirror entry (mostly after mvn failed).

I wonder is there a better way, so mvn skips the mirror if not available?

Added twist:  https://some-url-available-in-vpn-only has a public landing page that says: go use vpn.

Comment: Perhaps you can work with profiles: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#profiles. Active by default but disable it by using `-P-<value of id>`. I haven't tried that for `settings.xml`, but it works fine with `pom.xml`.

Comment: Mirrors don’t work in profiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible in simple native way.

There is an open issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5698
with proposition to define `mirrors` in `profiles`

Now you must maintain `settings.xml` for home use and for corporate use in different files ... or edit `settings` as you wrote.

One of way is to have two files and in order to easy switch I have defined function in my `.bash_profile` like:

```bash
function _ms_home {
    echo "Switch default maven settings to home"
    pushd ~/.m2 > /dev/null
    ln -sfv settings-home.xml settings.xml
    popd > /dev/null
}

function _ms_work {
    echo "Switch default maven settings to work"
    pushd ~/.m2 > /dev/null
    ln -sfv settings-work.xml settings.xml
    popd > /dev/null
}
```

Finally I can simply execute in my shell: `_ms_work` or `_ms_home` according to current environment I work in.

Comment: Great solution. One variation could be curling for vpn and depending on results call one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

every time you (or your ide) run mvn, you can pass a custom settings.xml file
with proper mirror configuration.

something like [his](https://github.com/sombriks/using-sample-maven-package/tree/178cb50f3c34863d9be73496938c96a51f569357)